# Using JGit and CLI git

Tags: jenkins-workflow

We have a series of nodes, some of which have git client installed on them and others that do not. For those that do not, we would like to use JGit. Is this possible with Pipeline? From what I read on the [tutorial setup page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#setting-up) it appears that we need to remove standard Git and just leave JGit in order to use git on nodes that want to use JGit. We're afraid this will break others who are using nodes that directly call git CLI, or perhaps use it in unique circumstances that JGit doesn't cover.

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `checkout` step with `GitSCM`, which has an extension to specify the Git tool to use. The `git` step has only a handful of the most common options as a convenience.